# Separated sets in Basic Topology by Armstrong

Tags: general-topology, definition, connectedness

In Armstrong's Basic Topology, page 58, subsets $A$ and $B$ of a space $X$ are separated if

$\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$.

However, anywhere else I have looked defines separated sets with the condition

$A \cap \bar{B} = \bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$.

These are clearly not equivalent, so is the definition in Armstrong non-standard?

Edit: removed faulty example

Comment: I think your last argument is incorrect. If $Y = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, then $(0, \infty)$ is open in $Y$. Hence $(-\infty, 0)$ is closed in $Y$. Thus $\overline{ (-\infty, 0) } = (-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: General Topology by R.Engelking defines $A$ and $B$ to be separated iff $\bar A \cap B=A\cap \bar B=\phi.$ (Bottom of page 68, following theorem 2.1.6).....Elsewhere, he defines a separated family as a set $F$ of subsets such that $\forall f\in F\;(\phi=f\cap Cl(\cup (F$ \ $\{f\})\;)).$ This is also called a discrete family.

Comment: I would think so.  His version is sometimes called completeiy separated.